# How can I input Uyghur language in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, right-to-left

I have been learning LaTeX for several weeks and now I am confident enough to write some academic papers in English. However, when I tried to input my mother language - Uyghur (Uighur), I had some difficulties and I could not do it even I watched some Youtube tutorials. Anyone can help me to solve this? My question may sound a bit silly, but anyway, please help ! I have many things to write in my own language using LaTeX.
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ
 For reference    [script=Uyghur] {UKIJ}

Comment: Welcome! Can you please post the code for a minimal document which includes some relevant input? Would you have `شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ`? You probably want to use `polyglossia` and XeLaTeX. Can you also give the names of some fonts people might have which support this script?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! UKIJ Tuz Tom, UKIJ Xet, UKIJ Basma.......are some of the fonts which might be useful.

Comment: If these letters are available in unicode, you could use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B2}{\ensuremath{\beta}}` like Arno Trautmann did [here](https://wiki.neo-layout.org/browser/latex/Standard-LaTeX/uniinput.dtx)  for the [Neo keyboard](https://www.neo-layout.org). Then you can use pdflatex to compile.

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I can't read Uyghur, so I don't actually know if this is correct.

Neither `polyglossia` nor `babel` appear to support Uyghur out of the box. `ArabTeX` claims to, but I think you have to use Latin characters for input.

However, perhaps using Arabic settings with `polyglossia` and a Uyghur font gives the right output. Compile this with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{UKIJ Tuz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, do I have to shift from LaTeX to XeTeX ? Is it not possible to compile in within LaTeX?

Comment: Perhaps with `ArabTeX` you could use `latex` (I haven't used it), but I think for complex scripts and RTL scripts, it's just not worth the pain. Use `xelatex` and you can make use of all your OpenType fonts. It's also easy to mix RTL and LTR languages in the one document with `polyglossia` which will not work with `latex`.

Comment: If by "within LaTeX", you mean your editor environment, then you should be able to change its settings to use `xelatex` instead of `latex` and you won't notice the difference.

Comment: Your explanation helps a lot for me ! Thank you very much ,I will try XeLateX.

Comment: I like the "disclaimer" part most.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, this works in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[openany]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{framed}

\geometry{left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{uyghur}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[uyghur]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[uyghur]{tt}
          [Language=Default]{ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}


\title{ سالام Latex}
\author{LaTex سىناق بېتى}
\date{\foreignlanguage{uyghur}{\localedate{2021}{6}{30}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{otherlanguage}{uyghur}
\noindent{\color{red} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ 
\end{otherlanguage}

Hello World! Here you can write Left-to-Right text, and also {ئۇيغۇر تىلى. 
There is a formula $E = mc^2$  here you are. \\

Write framed text with custom font like this: \\
\begin{framed}
\begin{otherlanguage}{uyghur}
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
$$ \boxed{F(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx}$$
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{framed}
\par
Write Formula  with custom font like this: \\
\begin{otherlanguage}{uyghur}% And set the font family here.
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\

\noindent\colorbox{apricot}{شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ} \\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus/Amiri sample]

I picked the Libertinus and Amiri font families by Khaled Hosny, which go well together, but you can use any fonts that work in your word processor.

Comment: There is also some tentative code for Uyghur hyphenation: https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.57.html#uyghur-hyphenation-lua . The hyphenation patterns are under development and afaik they haven't been released.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, the [polyglossia](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia) package adds support to the Uyghur language. An example code is pasted below. You can also find other related codes in my Github repo: https://github.com/neouyghur/uyghur-latex.

```
%&xelatex-uyghur
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url,amsmath}
%\usepackage[textwidth=5cm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
\usepackage{abstract}

\setdefaultlanguage{uyghur}
%\newfontfamily\uyghurfont[Script=Arabic,Extension=.otf,Scale=1,Mapping=uyghur-arabic-hyphenation,HyphenChar={^^^^f4ff}]{Amiri-Regular}
\newfontfamily\uyghurfont[Script=Arabic,Extension=.ttf,Scale=1,Mapping=uyghur-arabic-hyphenation,HyphenChar={^^^^06d4}]{UKIJZilwa}
%\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily

\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\title{لاتېكىس قوللانمىسى}
\author{neouyghur}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\lccode"06AD="0628
\catcode"06AD=11
\lccode"06AF="0628
\catcode"06AF=11
\lccode"06BE="062F
\catcode"06BE=11
\lccode"06C6="0627
\catcode"06C6=11
\lccode"06C7="0627
\catcode"06C7=11
\lccode"06C8="0627
\catcode"06C8=11
\lccode"06CB="06CB
\catcode"06CB=11
\lccode"06D0="0649
\catcode"06D0=11
\lccode"06D5="0627
\catcode"06D5=11
\lccode"062A="0628
\catcode"062A=11
\lccode"062C="0628
\catcode"062C=11
\lccode"062E="0628
\catcode"062E=11
\lccode"062F="062F
\catcode"062F=11
\lccode"063A="0628
\catcode"063A=11
\lccode"064A="064A
\catcode"064A=11
\lccode"067E="0628
\catcode"067E=11
\lccode"200D="200D
\catcode"200D=11
\lccode"0626="0626
\catcode"0626=11
\lccode"0627="0627
\catcode"0627=11
\lccode"0628="0628
\catcode"0628=11
\lccode"0631="062F
\catcode"0631=11
\lccode"0632="062F
\catcode"0632=11
\lccode"0633="0628
\catcode"0633=11
\lccode"0634="0628
\catcode"0634=11
\lccode"0641="0628
\catcode"0641=11
\lccode"0642="0628
\catcode"0642=11
\lccode"0643="0628
\catcode"0643=11
\lccode"0644="0628
\catcode"0644=11
\lccode"0645="0628
\catcode"0645=11
\lccode"0646="0628
\catcode"0646=11
\lccode"0648="0627
\catcode"0648=11
\lccode"0649="0649
\catcode"0649=11
\lccode"0686="0628
\catcode"0686=11
\lccode"0698="062F
\catcode"0698=11
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{abstract}
    ئۇيغۇرلار شىنجاڭ ئۇيغۇر ئاپتونوم رايونىنىڭ ھەقىقىي ئىگىلىرى ۋە مىراسخورلىرى بولۇپ، بۇ رايوندا توپلىشىپ ياشايدىغان غوللۇق، يەرلىك مىللەت ۋە ئاپتونومىيە ھوقۇقى يۈرگۈزگۈچى مىللەت. ئۇيغۇرلار پارچە ھالەتتە، جۇڭگونىڭ بىر قاتار چوڭ شەھەرلىرىدە خىزمەت ۋە تىجارەت قىلىدۇ. ئۇيغۇرلار شىنجاڭ ئۇيغۇر ئاپتونوم رايونىدىن باشقا، يەنە جۇڭگو، قازاقىستان، قىرغىزىستان، ئۆزبېكىستان، تاجىكىستان، تۈركمەنىستان (ئاساسلىقى بايرام ئەلى رايونى)، پاكىستان، ئەرەبىستان، تۈركىيە، ئاۋسترالىيە، گېرمانىيە، نورۋىگىيە، گوللاندىيە، شىۋىتسىيە، فىنلاندىيە، بېلگىيە، روسيە، ئامېرىكا قاتارلىق دۆلەتلەردە كۆرۈنەرلىك نوپۇستا، مۇئەييەن جامائەت تۈركۈمى شەكلىدە ياشايدۇ. مەن بۇ يەردە ئۇيغۇرچە يېزىپ سىناپ بېقىۋاتىمەن.
\end{abstract}


\part{ئۇيغۇرلار ھەققىدە}

\chapter{ئۇيغۇرلار}

\section{ئۇيغۇرلار ۋە ئۇلارنىڭ تۇرمۇش مەدەنىيىتى}

ئۇيغۇرلار شىنجاڭ ئۇيغۇر ئاپتونوم رايونىنىڭ ھەقىقىي ئىگىلىرى ۋە مىراسخورلىرى بولۇپ، بۇ رايوندا توپلىشىپ ياشايدىغان غوللۇق، يەرلىك مىللەت ۋە ئاپتونومىيە ھوقۇقى يۈرگۈزگۈچى مىللەت. ئۇيغۇرلار پارچە ھالەتتە، جۇڭگونىڭ بىر قاتار چوڭ شەھەرلىرىدە خىزمەت ۋە تىجارەت قىلىدۇ. ئۇيغۇرلار شىنجاڭ ئۇيغۇر ئاپتونوم رايونىدىن باشقا، يەنە جۇڭگو، قازاقىستان، قىرغىزىستان، ئۆزبېكىستان، تاجىكىستان، تۈركمەنىستان (ئاساسلىقى بايرام ئەلى رايونى)، پاكىستان، ئەرەبىستان، تۈركىيە، ئاۋسترالىيە، گېرمانىيە، نورۋىگىيە، گوللاندىيە، شىۋىتسىيە، فىنلاندىيە، بېلگىيە، روسيە، ئامېرىكا قاتارلىق دۆلەتلەردە كۆرۈنەرلىك نوپۇستا، مۇئەييەن جامائەت تۈركۈمى شەكلىدە ياشايدۇ.

\begin{english}
The \textbf{Uyghurs}\footnote{%
    From \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghurs}}  have traditionally inhabited a series of oases scattered across the Taklamakan Desert within the Tarim Basin. These oases have historically existed as independent states or were controlled by many civilizations including China, the Mongols, the Tibetans and various Turkic policies. The Uyghurs gradually started to become islamized in the 10th century and most Uyghurs identified as Muslims by the 16th century. Islam has since played an important role in Uyghur culture and identity. 
\end{english}

\section{نىكاھ}
ئۇيغۇرلاردا نىكاھ مۇناسىۋىتى بىلەن چاي ئىچكۈزۈش، توي ئالدىدىكى مەسلىھەت چايلىرى، نىكاھ ئوقۇپ قىز-يىگىتنىڭ رازىلىقىنى ئېلىش، توي مۇراسىمى، يىگىت-قىزلار ئولتۇرۇشى، قۇدىلار چىللاقلىرى ئىزچىل ساقلىنىپ كەلدى. ئۇيغۇرلاردا دەپنە مۇراسىمى ھەرقايسى دىنىي مەدەنىيەتلەر تەسىرىدە ھەرخىل بولسىمۇ، ئەمما مېيىتنى پاكىزە يۇيۇپ كېپەنلەش، ھازىدارلار ئاق رومال سېلىپ، ئاق بەلۋاغ باغلاپ يىغا-زارە قىلىش، مېيىتنىڭ نامىزىنى چۈشۈرۈش، جىنازىنى ئالمىشىپ تالىشىپ كۈتۈرۈپ قەبرىستانلىققا ئېلىپ بېرىش، لەھەتتە مېيىتنىڭ يۈزىنى قىبلە (غەرب) تەرەپكە قىلىپ ياتقۇزۇش، ئىچ گۆرنىڭ ئاغزىنى كېسەك بىلەن ئېتىپ، تاش گۆرنى توپا بىلەن كۆمۈش، قەبرە بېشىدا مېيىتنىڭ ئىجابىي تەرىپىگە گۇۋاھلىق بېرىش، قەبرە تېشى-گۈمبەز ئورنىتىش، مېيىتنىڭ يەتتە، قىرىق، يىل نەزىرلىرىنى ئۆتكۈزۈش ئادەتلىرى بىردەك ئىزچىل بۇلۇپ كەلدى. ئۇيغۇرلار ۋە ئۇلارنىڭ ئەجدادلىرى مېيىت سۆڭىكىنى كاھىش (ساپال) ساندۇققا سېلىپ يەرلىككە قۇيۇش، مېيىتنى تاش گۆرگە كۆمۈش، مېيىتنى ئاستىغا ياغاچ شادا قويۇلغان گۆرگە ياتقۇزۇپ، ئۈستىگە قىزىل تۇپراق ۋە قۇم تۆكۈپ كۆمۈش، شام گۆرگە قويۇش قاتارلىق دەپنە قىلىش ئۇسۇللىرىنىمۇ قوللاندى. 

\section{ھېيت-ئايەم}


\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
\caption{ئا رەسىم.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
        \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline\hline
        1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \hline
        2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
        \hline
        3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
        \hline
        4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
        \hline
        5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{بىر سىناق جەدۋەل}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
    \label{test}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
    \label{test}
\end{equation}


\chapter{مەڭگۈ تاش يادىكارلىقلىرى}

\section{تەس مەڭگۈ تېشى}
بۇ مەڭگۈ تاش يادىكارلىقى 1976- يىلى موڭغۇلىيەدىكى تەس دەرياسىنىڭ سول قىرغىدىكى نوغۇن تولغوي ئىگىزلىكىنىڭ يېنىدىن تېپىلغانلىقى ئۈچۈن، «تەس مەڭگۈ تېشى» دەپ ئاتالغان. «تەس مەڭگۈ تېشى» ئورخۇن ئۇيغۇر خانلىقى دەۋرىگە مەنسۇپ يادىكارلىقلارنىڭ ئىچىدە بۇزغۇنچىلىققا ئۇچرىشى ئېغىرراق. ئەڭ مۇھىم بولغان يازما يادىكارلىق. ئۇنىڭدا بۆگۈ قاغان (759- 780- يىللار) ئەجدادى (دادىسى) بولغان ئەل ئەتمىش بىلگە قاغان (مويۇنچۇر، 747- 759- يىللار9 دەۋرىگىچە بولغان ئۇيغۇر قاغانلىرىنىڭ تارىخى، جۈملىدىن بىرىنچى ۋە ئىككىنچى ئۇيغۇر خانلىقىنىڭ تەقدىرى. كۆل بىلگە قاغان ۋە ئەل ئەتمىش بىلگە قاغان باشچىلىقىدىكى ئۈچىنچى ئۇيغۇر خانلىقىنىڭ بەرپا بولۇشى قاتارلىق مەسىلىلەر ھەققىدە مەلۇمات بېرىلگەن. بۇ ھەقتىكى بىر قىسىم مەزمۇنلار كونا- يېڭى تاڭنامىلەردە ئۇچرىمايدۇ. شۇڭا تەس مەڭگۈ تېشىدىكى مەلۇماتلار زور سېلىشتۇرما قىممەتكە ئىگە. تەتقىقاتلارغا قارىغاندا، «تەس مەڭگۈ تېشى» نىڭ ئاپتورى مويۇنچۇر قاغاننىڭ يېقىن تۇققىنى تۈپەك ئالىپ شۇل دېگەن كىشى بولۇپ، مەڭگۈ تاشنى قاغان يېڭىدىن تەختكە چىققان ۋاقىتتا توغرىسى 761- 762- يىللىرى ئورنىتىلغان، دېيىشكە بولىدۇ.


\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            \hline
            Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
            \hline\hline
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
            \hline
            2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
            \hline
            3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
            \hline
            4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
            \hline
            5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{يەنە بىر سىناق جەدۋەل}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\section{تېرخىن مەڭگۈ تېشى}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
    \caption{ب رەسىم.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}


\begin{equation}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2
    \label{test}
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{latexcompanion} 
    Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
    \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
    Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
    
    \bibitem{einstein} 
    ئو. تۇرسۇن. 
    \textit{لاتېكىست قوللانمىسى}. (ئۇيغۇرچە) 
    [\textit{بىر ژورنال}]. , 322(10):891–921, 1905.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using Arabic sicrpt .sty in Latex.~
talk is cheap show me the code.
My Files:

```
code.tex
uytex.sty
./uyFonts/
------ UKIJ Ekran.ttf
------ UKIJ Qolyazma.ttf
------ UKIJ Teng.ttf
```

note, uyFonts directory needed.
code.tex:

```
\documentclass[openany]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{uytex}
\geometry{left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}

\title{\textu{ سالام Latex}}
\author{\textu{LaTex سىناق بېتى}}
\date{\udate}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent{\color{red} \rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}

\utext{
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ 
}

Hello World! Here you can write Left-to-Right text. 
There is a formula $E = mc^2$  here you are. \\

Write framed text with custom font like this: \\
\begin{framed}
\utext{{\uqolyaz
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
$$ \boxed{F(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx}$$
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ
 }}
 \end{framed}
\par
Write Formula  with custom font like this: \\

\utext{{\uteng
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.\\
}}

\utext{
\colorbox{apricot}{\textu{شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ}} \\
شۇنىسى ئېنىقكى ئەر-ئاياللار مەلۇم نەرسىلەرگە نىسبەتەن بىرلىككە كېلەلمەيدۇ.
}
\end{document}
```

uytex.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{uytex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

% SET Main & Mono Font % Declare Ssome Fonts with short name
\newfontfamily{\uekran}[Path = uyFonts/]{UKIJ Ekran.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\uqolyaz}[Path = uyFonts/]{UKIJQolyazma.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\uteng}[Path = uyFonts/]{UKIJTeng.ttf}

\setmainfont [Path = uyFonts/] {UKIJ Ekran.ttf}
\setsansfont [Path = uyFonts/] {UKIJQolyazma.ttf}
\setmonofont [Path = uyFonts/] {UKIJTeng.ttf}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%Rewrite Date Format
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{\number\month}
\newcommand\nnz{\textarabic{يانىۋار}}
\ifnum \value{num}=2 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{فېۋرال}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=3 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{مارت}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=4 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ئاپرېل}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=5 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ماي}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=6 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ئىيۇن}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=7 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ئىيۇل}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=8 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ئاۋغۇسېت}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=9 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{سېنتەبىر}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=10 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{ئۆكتەبىر}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=11 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{نويابىر}}\fi
\ifnum \value{num}=12 {\renewcommand\nnz{\textarabic{دېكابىر}}\fi

\newcommand{\utoday}{\textarabic{\number\year -يىلى \number\month -ئاي \number\day -كۈنى}}
\newcommand{\udate}{\textarabic{\number\year -يىل \number\day - \nnz}}
\newcommand{\udates}{\textarabic{\number\day/\number\month/\number\year}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------


% Renew \begin{Arabic} Area with \bu and \utext{}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\bu}{\begin{Arabic}}
\newcommand{\eu}{\end{Arabic}}
\newcommand\textu{\textarabic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\utext{\begingroup\@utext}
\newcommand\@utext[1]{\endgroup\newlinechar`\^^M
\scantokens{\begin{Arabic}%
#1}
\end{Arabic}%
\newlinechar`^^J }% back to LaTeX's default
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%Set Border Indented size
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Everything has done!
[image]

---

[image]