# I'm using the newspaper package, How do I make the title of my newspaper title in Uyghur or Farsi or Arabic

Tags: arabic, newspaper

I have included Arabic in the package. but I can't display the headline of the newspaper.

```
\documentclass{article}
%In the preamble section include the arabtex and utf8 packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex} % Required for arab
\usepackage{utf8}
```

I'm assuming that I need to change the gothic font in the headline of the newspaper. Gothic font does not support Arabic.

```
\usepackage{newspaper}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{اويغور گازتي}
\SetHeaderName{اويغور گازتي}
\SetPaperLocation{اورومچي}
\SetPaperSlogan{اورومچي الغه}
\SetPaperPrice{1.7}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
%%%
\usepackage{picinpar}

\usepackage{newspaper-mod}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcode{utf8}



\begin{multicols}{3}
\closearticle
 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Some Uighur letters are not in Arabic or Persian, can I add them to the text?

I summarize:

1. Most important: Arabic(Uyghur) newspaper headline compiled successfully.
2. If it is possible to add Uighur and Arabic, then add.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se!

Comment: The `newspaper` package relies on legacy fonts, pre-Unicode. You will need a suitable modern font (e,g, a Unicode .otf font) and a package to handle it (`fontspec`); a package to handle RTL layout (e.g. `babel`); and xelatex. or lualatex to compile. Search this site for `xepersian`, or for Arabic/Farsi questions, and related questions, to get a general idea. I'm unable to provide a full answer in a short quick comment. I'll see what I can find. The main step will be finding a suitable font.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378048/how-can-i-input-uyghur-language-in-latex

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

[image: ug]

The columns are still LTR left-to-right, though.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\uyg[Script=Arabic]{UKIJBasma}
\usepackage{newspaper}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Color=blue,Scale=1.1,Script=Arabic]{UKIJTuz}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{{\uyg اويغور گازتي}}
\SetHeaderName{{ \uyg اويغور گازتي}}
\SetPaperLocation{{\uyg اورومچي}}
\SetPaperSlogan{\uyg اورومچي الغه}
\SetPaperPrice{1.7}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
%%%
\usepackage{picinpar}

%\usepackage{newspaper-mod}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\setcode{utf8}


\begin{Arabic}
\begin{multicols}{3}
x x x

{\uyg اويغور گازتي}


{ \uyg اويغور گازتي}

{\uyg اورومچي}

{\uyg اورومچي الغه}

x x x

{\uyg اويغور گازتي}


{ \uyg اويغور گازتي}

{\uyg اورومچي}

{\uyg اورومچي الغه}

\closearticle
\textenglish{From Wikipedia: Solar system}
{

قۇياش سىستېمىسىنىڭ ئاساسلىق ئەزالىرى ئىچىدىن سىرتىغا : مېركۇرىي ، ۋىنىرا ، يەرشارى ، مارس ، يۇپىتېر ، ساتۇرن ، ئۇران ، نېپتۇن . قۇياش سىستىمىسى قۇياشنى مەركەز قىلغان ، ھەمدە بارلىق قۇياشنىڭ ئېغىرلىق كۇچ تەسىرىگە ئۇچرايدىغان ئاسمان جىسىمىنىڭ بىرلەشمىسى : 8 سەييارە ، ئاز دىگەندىمۇ 165 دانە ھەمراھى بار ، 5 دانە بايقالغان پەتەك يۇلتۇز ۋە مىليونلىغان قۇياش سىستېمىسى كىچىك ئاسمان جىسىملىرىدىن تۇزەلگەن . بۇ كىچىك ئاسمان جى ...
}

 \closearticle
\end{multicols}
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

---

Added `luabidi`:

[image: ug2]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\uyg[Script=Arabic]{UKIJ Basma}
\newfontfamily\uygb[Script=Arabic,Color=red,Scale=2]{UKIJ Ekran}\usepackage{newspaper}

%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}


%\usepackage[bidi=basic,english,Arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Color=blue,Scale=1.1,Script=Arabic]{UKIJ Tuz}


%\usepackage{bidi} % compile with xelatex
\usepackage{luabidi} % compile with lualatex

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\newcommand\loc{\uyg اورومچي}
\SetPaperName{{\Huge\uyg\textarabic{اويغور گازتي}}}
\SetHeaderName{\textarabic{{\Large\uygb اويغور گازتي}}}
\SetPaperLocation{{\loc}}
\SetPaperSlogan{{\large\textarabic{ اورومچي الغه}}}
\SetPaperPrice{1.7}

\title{}
\setRTLmain

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{Arabic}
%\begin{RTL}\RTLmulticolumns
\begin{multicols}{3}
x x x

{\uyg اويغور گازتي}


{ \uyg اويغور گازتي}

{\uyg اورومچي}

{\uyg اورومچي الغه}

x x x

{\uyg اويغور گازتي}


{ \uyg اويغور گازتي}

{\uyg اورومچي}

{\uyg اورومچي الغه}

\closearticle
\textenglish{From Wikipedia: Solar system}

{

قۇياش سىستېمىسىنىڭ ئاساسلىق ئەزالىرى ئىچىدىن سىرتىغا : مېركۇرىي ، ۋىنىرا ، يەرشارى ، مارس ، يۇپىتېر ، ساتۇرن ، ئۇران ، نېپتۇن . قۇياش سىستىمىسى قۇياشنى مەركەز قىلغان ، ھەمدە بارلىق قۇياشنىڭ ئېغىرلىق كۇچ تەسىرىگە ئۇچرايدىغان ئاسمان جىسىمىنىڭ بىرلەشمىسى : 8 سەييارە ، ئاز دىگەندىمۇ 165 دانە ھەمراھى بار ، 5 دانە بايقالغان پەتەك يۇلتۇز ۋە مىليونلىغان قۇياش سىستېمىسى كىچىك ئاسمان جىسىملىرىدىن تۇزەلگەن . بۇ كىچىك ئاسمان جى ...
}


 \closearticle

\uyg

قۇياش سىستېمىسىنىڭ ئاساسلىق ئەزالىرى ئىچىدىن سىرتىغا : مېركۇرىي ، ۋىنىرا ، يەرشارى ، مارس ، يۇپىتېر ، ساتۇرن ، ئۇران ، نېپتۇن . قۇياش سىستىمىسى قۇياشنى مەركەز قىلغان ، ھەمدە بارلىق قۇياشنىڭ ئېغىرلىق كۇچ تەسىرىگە ئۇچرايدىغان ئاسمان جىسىمىنىڭ بىرلەشمىسى : 8 سەييارە ، ئاز دىگەندىمۇ 165 دانە ھەمراھى بار ، 5 دانە بايقالغان پەتەك يۇلتۇز ۋە مىليونلىغان قۇياش سىستېمىسى كىچىك ئاسمان جىسىملىرىدىن تۇزەلگەن . بۇ كىچىك ئاسمان جى ...


قۇياش سىستېمىسىنىڭ ئاساسلىق ئەزالىرى ئىچىدىن سىرتىغا : مېركۇرىي ، ۋىنىرا ، يەرشارى ، مارس ، يۇپىتېر ، ساتۇرن ، ئۇران ، نېپتۇن . قۇياش سىستىمىسى قۇياشنى مەركەز قىلغان ، ھەمدە بارلىق قۇياشنىڭ ئېغىرلىق كۇچ تەسىرىگە ئۇچرايدىغان ئاسمان جىسىمىنىڭ بىرلەشمىسى : 8 سەييارە ، ئاز دىگەندىمۇ 165 دانە ھەمراھى بار ، 5 دانە بايقالغان پەتەك يۇلتۇز ۋە مىليونلىغان قۇياش سىستېمىسى كىچىك ئاسمان جىسىملىرىدىن تۇزەلگەن . بۇ كىچىك ئاسمان جى ...


 \closearticle
\end{multicols}
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```